# UserDefaults .set not being picked up by state variable in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am attempting to to detect whether a user has onboarded or not e.g. launched the app. When I access the `UserDefaults.standard.bool` directly I can see the change but when I attempt to access it through the `@State` it retains the original `false` value.

As a workaround I directly change the value to `true`, but I have a feeling this isn't the way to do this.

How can I get the `@State` variable to pick up the change when changing the `UserDefaults` object without having to close and restart the app? I want the user to onboard, click a button, then switch immediately to the main app view.

```swift
@State var userOnboarded: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "userOnboarded")
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if userOnboarded {
                Text("PLACEHOLDER: Main App View")
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "userOnboarded")
                    userOnboarded = true
                    print(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "userOnboarded"))
                }) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Click circle to onboard.")
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why would it? Use AppStorage instead.

Comment: Ahh ok, I wasn't aware of that. I'll take a look!

Comment: You set the `@State` with the value of the `UserDefaults` at the time of init, but from that point on, `@State` is separate.

Comment: @Yrb thank you for that insight! I'll take what I've gotten here and see what I can do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SwiftUI there is a dedicated wrapper to watch UserDefaults. As previously mentioned in your comments, it's called `@AppStorage` and it's used like so.

```
@AppStorage("userOnboarded") var userOnboarded: Bool = false
```

It functions similarly to a UserDefault but will refresh the view and set the data when the value changes.

```
Button(action: {
    userOnboarded = true
    print(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "userOnboarded"))
}) //....
```

Notice in the button, we set the userOnboarded to true, this will update and refresh your view as well as update the user default value.

Comment: Thank you for this explicit answer